# Search for a string in command line output

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, prompt

I want to search for the string "**virtual**" in "**system model**" attribute of '**sysinfo**' command. The command should be successful if 'virtual' is found in the **'system model: -------------------------'** i.e. output of the systeminfo. It should not search for 'virtual' in whole output of systeminfo command but should do in system model attribute only.
For example the command

```
systeminfo | findstr /i "system model"
```

I will get something like

```
System Model:              HP Compaq dc7800p Small Form Factor
```

in the above line of the output i want to search for string virtual, and want to manipulate using errorlevel.  So please help me to do this.

Following is the one I tried which was not correct.
Or help me if i can use regular expressions

```
systeminfo | findstr /i /R  "system model: virtual machine" > nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
   echo virtual machine
) ELSE (
   echo physical machine
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```sh
systeminfo | findstr /I /B /C:"system model" | findstr /I "virtual"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo virtual machine
) else (
    echo real machine
)
```

I've tested in on a real and virtual system and it works fine on WinXp and Win7. 
Note that the `system model` string is only used in English Windows versions. Windows versions in other languages will use a different names.

Comment: this finds any file, that starts with "system" OR "model". To search for the string "system model" use `findstr /i /b /C:"system model"` (no problem in this special case, because there is no line in `systeminfo` that starts with "Model")

Comment: @Stephan you are right! It works right now, but could be a problem in the future if Windows changes the information generated by systeminfo. I'll add the /C: to my answer. Thanks for mentioning it!